# Java ImageView not appearing on screen

Tags: java, javafx

Okay so this is the code I used. Most of it comes from the JavaFX tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm).

I wanted my program to load a picture when I clicked the button. But it will do the prints but it will not load the picture.

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.image.*;;

    public class Browser extends Application {


        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.setText("Test");
            Image ph1 = new Image("ph1.jpg");
            ImageView disp1 = new ImageView();


            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Test1"); 

                    disp1.setImage(ph1);

                    System.out.println("Test2");
                }
            });

            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            root.getChildren().add(btn);

     Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

            primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);

        }
    }
```

Comment: You never add the ImageView to the scene graph anywhere.  You need something like `root.getChildren().add(disp1);`, though the layout would be weird with that.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the `disp1` `ImageView` to the `root` `StackPane`.

Try this:

```
StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(btn);
root.getChildren().add(disp1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have never worked with Java before and am now beginning to understand how it works thanks to this project I'm building. Thank you so much for your quick reply it was really appreciated!

Comment: @deeup511 I'm glad I could help. Good luck.